# How to make text that has more width then its container to move left, not right?

Tags: css

I have a text in the div with 5px margin-right. If the container div becomes narrow the text moves out of the container and there is no 5px margin anymore.
Is it possible to keep this margin from the right and make text go out from the left side of the container, not right? Without using position:absolute

Here is the sample

```css
.box {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 170px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: right;
}

.text {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.box2 {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box box1">
  <div class="text">Sample text</div>
</div>
<div class="box box2">
  <div class="text">Sample text2</div>
</div>
```

https://jsbin.com/tudutun/

Comment: check the flexbox soliution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47926294/8620333 ... the duplicate is hiding the overflow but you aren't obliged to do the same (add `display: flex;justify-content: flex-end;` to box element)

Answer (score 0):

remove white-space: nowrap; from .box class

Answer (score 0):

use overflow properties to your div container

Comment: Could you give the asker a little more context, i.e. how you would use the overflow property expressed as code?